# Passing multiple parameters in XML

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.7

I am working with Magento SOAP v1, the documentation says I can pass optional parameters. However, nothing I have tried is allowing this and the call just bounces if I try to send more than one parameter within the args tag.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html

[image: Image of args]

I have tried the following to no avail, my lack of XML has got me.

[image: Mage multi args]

However, when I only pass one parameter (arg) it works. 
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found (the hard way) Magento SOAP v1 does not support multiple parameters.
You need to use host.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1, They do say in the intro v2 was created to help in .NET & Java applications.

Still, I could be wrong & wanted to post an "Answer" in case anyone else was having this issue. If some Magento Guru knows a way to do the above, please chime in.